# Unit testing MessageSender for Azure Functions V2

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, moq, azureservicebus

I am trying to find the best approach for using MessageSender in my Azure function as the connection to ServiceBus, in order to unit test it. I have been unable to find the best way to write my code to unit test it.

**Code**

```
public static class SomeFunction
{        
    [FunctionName("SomeFunction")]
    public static async Task Run(
          [ServiceBusTrigger("someQueue", Connection = ConnectionString)]Message message
        , [ServiceBus("someQueue", Connection = ConnectionString")]MessageSender messagesQueue
        , MessageReceiver receiver
        , string lockToken)
    {
        ...some code
    }
}
```

I tried to change the `MessageSender` to `IMessageSender` but got the following binding error

***Binding Error***

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "Can't bind ServiceBus to type 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.IMessageSender."
```

Then switched it back to the `MessageSender` and tried mocking it and once I ran my test I got the error below.

**Unit Test Example**

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Run_ValidMessage_Expect_Run_Succesfully()
{
    var sbBuilder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(ActualSbConnectionString);
    Mock<MessageSender>sender = new Mock<MessageSender>(sbBuilder, RetryPolicy.Default);
    SomeFunction.Run(_sender.Object);
}
```

```
Error: 
threw exception: 
    System.ArgumentException: The argument  is null or white space.
  Stack Trace: 
    at MessageSender.ctor(String entityPath, String transferDestinationPath, Nullable`1 entityType, ServiceBusConnection serviceBusConnection, ICbsTokenProvider cbsTokenProvider, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
    at MessageSender.ctor(String connectionString, String entityPath, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
```

I have been unable to write the code with a working unit test and function. any pointers would be helpful.

Edit: included omitted args

Answer (score 1):

From your code, there are few errors, firstly it should be `ServiceBusTrigger` binding not the `ServiceBus` cause you don't show your trigger bingding or you omit it. Then if your trigger is `ServiceBusTrigger`, you could only bind `MessageReceiver`, `MessageSender` is for `ServiceBus`. [Sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/b9c8afd097ea270f693b1f1e897c14e27b838eec/test/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.EndToEndTests/ServiceBusEndToEndTests.cs#L376).

And the below is my test code, ServiceBusTrigger to receive the message, ServiceBus to send the message. I use the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus 3.0.3`.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ConnectionString")]
        MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
        ILogger log, 
        [ServiceBus("test", Connection = "ConnectionString")]MessageSender messagesQueue)
    {
        Console.Write(messageReceiver.Path);

        Message m1 = await messageReceiver.PeekAsync();

        await messagesQueue.SendAsync(m1);

    }
```

This works for me, you could have a try if this code is what you want. If you still have problem, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I included the items that I omitted. I am looking to unit-test the code.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I hit this issue and found a work around.

Instead of having the `MessageSender` as a parameter in the `Run` method, I ctor inject a `Func<MessageSender>` into the function class.

Note: I acknowledge it would probably be better if I could unit test without needing to go down this approach, but I couldn't get it working any other way...

e.g.

```cs
   public class SomeFunction
   {
      private readonly Func<IMessageSender> _messageSenderFactory;

      public SomeFunction(
         Func<IMessageSender> messageSenderFactory)
      {
         _messageSenderFactory = messageSenderFactory;
      }

      [FunctionName("SomeFunction")]
      public static async Task Run(
         [ServiceBusTrigger("someQueue", Connection = ConnectionString)]Message message,
         MessageReceiver receiver, 
         string lockToken)
      {
         // ...
         var messageSender = _messageSenderFactory.Invoke();
         await messageSender.SendAsync(message);
      }
   }
```

Have to register `Func<IMessageSender>` for DI in startup.cs:

```cs
         services.AddSingleton<Func<IMessageSender>>(() =>
            new MessageSender(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION"),
               Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("someQueue")));
```

Can then mock the `Func<IMessageSender>` in unit tests.